# npm install: install Couldn't read dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have started to  learn **Angular JS**. I am going through this, that is building simple [phonecat app](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

I am following the steps. **Node.js downloaded.**
Trying to execute this command: `npm install`

**Error occured:**
C:>npm install

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path C:\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directo
ry.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log

C:\>
```

Comment: You don't have a package.json file in your directory.

Comment: Duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722155/how-can-i-deal-with-this-npm-err).

Comment: Yes, I have: the path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Comment: If you're following the tutorial, then you must clone the project and then move into the directory. The directory must have a package.json file. Then, do npm install.

Comment: Thanks. "move into the directory" It helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before executing the command `npm install` 
Execute this `cd myproject` and then execute this: `npm install`

**Its solved.** Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't put the package.json file in root directory.
If you are starting fresh, you'll need to clone this repo. https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat

Answer (score 1):

Like Bilhan A said: you need to change to the folder where you cloned the project to. 
From your question I am assuming you are new to programming and want to learn Angularjs primarily. Node.js is not needed for this. If you really want to learn Angular, I recommend Tutorials like [this one](https://egghead.io/articles/new-to-angularjs-start-learning-here), which do not require node.js. When you understood how it works, come back to node.js and combine them.

Answer (score 1):

`name` field in `package.json` should be the same with name of your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the error displayed then simply update the npm,i face this issue now that's why i update here,it might be help some one

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Program F iles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" 
"install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\joy\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open     
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current    
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\joy\Desktop\TEMP\node\chatsys\npm-debug.log
```